# TMS AdvMemo - SQL syntax highlighting - style not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, syntax-highlighting, tms

I'm making a small application which has a syntax highlight for SQL, by using TMS's TADvMemo and TAdvSQLMemoStyler components. I've changed the default LineComment `'` property to `--` to respect SQL comment syntax. The issue I have is that I can not make the component to display the strings from SQL as I want, highlighted:

[image]

Even I'm creating a new style on the SQLMemoStyler component:

[image]

Any idea on this?

Comment: Ask TMS Support? It's free if you purchased the product, they have their own support forums, and they're much more familiar with their product.

Comment: I agree that asking the vendor for support is a good idea and likely your best option, however I also believe that asking here should also be a valid place for questions related to 3rd party controls. I have seen many questions that get dismissed because of that exact reason when they should all be valid here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set the `Style's Style` Type to `stBracket` instead of `stKeyWord`.